# Does WPF have mouse wheel scrolling up and down event

Tags: c#, wpf, mousewheel

I checked msdn. For event related to **mouse wheel**, there is only one option -- UIElement.MouseWheel

What I want to do is listening to mouse wheel scrolling forward(up) and backward(down) event.

Note: **Not** **clicking** the middle wheel button.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, there is just one event.  When you look at the MouseWheelEventArgs class there is a property Delta.  Delta is positive when the wheel is rotated away from the user and negative when the wheel is rotated toward the user.

Answer (score 14):

> For event related to mouse wheel, **there is only one option**

No, there are others.

There is also the `PreviewMouseWheel` (*which functions just like the `MouseWheel` event but is operates at a different point in the keyboard and mouse handling.*).

The Preview also has a `Delta` property which gives the direction of the wheel spin.

---

**Example**

```
private void PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta > 0)
        DoActionUp();

    else if (e.Delta < 0)
        DoActionDown();
}
```

Comment: Apart from suggesting the Preview version of the event (which you usually don't want to do unless there's a good reason), how is this any different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @JoeWhite Its not a preview as in the next version of WPF... it means to peek (take a preview) at what is the next value and is a valid event to use in WPF.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the next version of WPF. I asked why you're using the special-purpose PreviewMouseWheel event when the plain old MouseWheel event will work, and why you think it's better than the accepted answer.

Comment: The answer given said there was only one event, which is patently false. I am providing an alternative, is it better depends on the situation. There are many ways to program a solution; this is one other way. `Preview...` has worked for me in as much as doing a `peek` on a stack or a queue.

Comment: I like this answer because it gives the code as well. However, you don't need the PreviewMouseWheel. You can just use MouseWheel event.

Comment: Apparently, if the control uses the wheel (for example control with a scroll), then the event MouseWheel is not called at all while the event PreviewMouseWheel is called.

Comment: it's because of how routed events work in WPF. they use routing strategies, for instance tunneling (PreviewNNNEvent) or bubbling (NNNEvent): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/september/advanced-wpf-understanding-routed-events-and-commands-in-wpf